# How can I compile a GeoLite CSV file into MMDB again?

Tags: geoip, geoip2

I have made a few corrections to location names in a GeoLite2 CSV file.
My site only retrieves locations from the MMDB file, so how can I compile back the changed CSV file into the MMDB binary again.
I searched everywhere for a solution but can't find it.

Thanks for any tip.
Carlos

Answer (score 2):

Currently there are only 2 open source MMDB file writers:

- [MaxMind::DB::Writer](https://github.com/maxmind/MaxMind-DB-Writer-perl) (Perl language)
- [Go MaxMind DB Writer](https://github.com/maxmind/mmdbwriter) (Go language)

The second one unfortunately has only a subset of the features available for the Perl one, but it should be enough for writing a program that creates the MMDB file reading line by line the CSV one and creating the `mmdbtype` instances.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out our **[mmdbctl](https://github.com/ipinfo/mmdbctl)** utility tool.

[To convert a CSV file to an MMDB file](https://github.com/ipinfo/mmdbctl#importing) use the `import` command:

```bash
$ mmdbctl import --in data.csv --out data.mmdb
```

Instructions, features, and documentation are available here: [github.com/ipinfo/mmdbctl](https://github.com/ipinfo/mmdbctl).

Right now it only supports string data types, and not nested data types. See [this issue](https://github.com/ipinfo/mmdbctl/issues/2) for more information.

Comment: Note that `mmdbctl` currently only supports a subset of the mmdb format, and is not compatible with maxmind provided database files.

Comment: Thank you @Magnus. I wasn't aware of that when I made the comment, I have edited the comment to provide more context. I believe you are referring to this issue: https://github.com/ipinfo/mmdbctl/issues/2

Comment: Yes, that is the issue I am referring to.